# Caching issue - all page URLs showing same output page in browser unless hard refresh

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, caching

I have a WordPress site https://bustypalace.com (NSFW) on Ubuntu which when I setup, I enabled various caching methods.

I recently realized that while I'm not logged in as a WordPress user, all pages load the same (first page loaded) page. If I do a hard refresh in my web browser, it clears and shows the correct page.

I enabled http content caching following these instructions:
https://www.1and1.com/cloud-community/learn/web-server/apache/configure-http-content-caching-in-apache-on-ubuntu-1604/

I also added this to the .htaccess file in the /var/www/html directory:

```
# BEGIN EXPIRES

    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 days"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/plain "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-icon "access plus 1 year"

# END EXPIRES
```

I'm guessing this problem stems from some caching issue, so I tried to remove all caching methods that I applied (Yes, I restarted apache).

Unfortunately, the problem still persists even though according to https://gtmetrix.com/reports/bustypalace.com/GoVZdZtB browser caching is now disabled.

Anyone know how can I solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by disabling cache_disk:

```
sudo a2dismod cache_disk
```